# Datetime may not intersect other datetime for that user's activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

Might be a somewhat specific situation. And I kinda know how to do it in PHP/MySQL. But I was wondering if there was a faster way to do the following scenario:

A user has activities with a start- and end_date. (The activity starts at 12-10-2013 12:00:00 and ends at 12-10-2013 12:15:00  for example.)

Whenever the user creates a new activity. I want to check all the activities the user is part of(user `has_many: activities`) and see if none of the dates intersect with the date given for the new activity.

Since I'm pretty new to Rails I really don't know where to start searching for date comparisons and all...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using the [&](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-26) method of [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html) might help.

Comment: Does an activity have multiple users (implied in comment on answer below)? If so, is there not a UserActivity model that correlates Users and Activities?

Comment: The user can assign one or many users to a new activity. And yes; there is an association between the two.

Comment: Can you update the question to reflect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An overlap is defined as another activity for which the end date is greater than or equal to the new activity's start date, and for which the start date is less than or equal to the new activity's end date.

Since you only want to detect whether such a record already exists, an appropriate test would be:

```
if Activity.where("starts_at <= ?" , new_activity_end_date  ).
            where("ends_at   >= ?" , new_activity_start_date).
            exists?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular comparators for date/times in Ruby (ie: `>`, `<` and `==`).

Something like the following should do what you are looking for:

```
if current_user.activities.where("(starts_at <= ? AND ends_at >= ?) OR (starts_at >= ? AND starts_at <= ?)", start_datetime, start_datetime, start_datetime, end_datetime).count
  # There exist activities that fall between start_datetime and end_datetime
else
  # There exist no such activities
end
```

`(starts_at <= start_datetime AND ends_at >= start_datetime)` checks whether an event starts before and ends after `start_datetime`.

`(starts_at >= start_datetime AND starts_at <= end_datetime)` checks whether an event starts between `start_datetime` and `end_datetime`.

Comment: But only for the clients that are involved though? I think I need to get all the clients that are involved in the new activity, and check all their start and end_dates...?

Comment: This is the first time that the word "clients" has appeared, so I suspect that there is more to the requirement than is stated ;)

Comment: Updated the answer to only query activities that the currently logged in user belongs to (assuming you are using something like Devise for authentication).

Comment: @DavidAldridge Clients = Users :) My bad!

Answer (score 0):

We must check that all this three kinds of intersection do not happen:

- our activity must not happen within another activity
- our activity must not start before another ends
- our activity must not ends after another starts

We can do that using something like this:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :must_not_be_intersected

  def intersected?
    params = {
      :start => start_date,
      :end => end_date
    }

    Activity::where('start_date <= :start AND end_date >= :end', params)
      .where('(start_date >= :start AND start_date <= :end) OR (end_date >= :start AND end_date <= :end)', params)
      .exists?
  end

private

  def must_not_be_intersected
    errors.add :base, 'Other task running on the same period' if intersected?
  end

end
```